# Write a program to convert the age of human in years and display the age in month,week and days

Tags: php

im new with the php and still studying about php and more. i have a question.
How to convert the age of human in years and then display the age in months,week and days.
(hint:1years=365days). i hope anyone could help me.thanks

Comment: School assignments will not be done here.

Comment: hint not every year is 365 days

Comment: @Dagon sometimes feburary has 28, 29, even 30 :D

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$previousDate = '1986-09-04 14:05:43';
$startDate = new DateTime($previousDate);
$endDate = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $endDate->diff($startDate);
echo $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days');
```